# issues with mysql, specifically the sql function

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to insert the following code on SQL, however it won't work.
What's the problem :O

Content

```
$share_text="<img src='http://dosha.re/i/Uvhg.png'/>";
```

> (it's an IMG tag, except stackoverflow won't show the code.)

```
$sql.=", '$share_text'";
```

As you can tell, Sharetext does include an img extension but for some reason i get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'http://dosha.re/i/Uvhg.png'/>', 1, '', 'Tue Apr 2 2013', '09:51
>   PM')' at line 1

Comment: Thanks jack haha, that was a noob mistake on my part.

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: @hjpotter92 How can you tell OP is using `mysql_` functions?

Comment: I use mysqli for persistent connections but that's about it.

Comment: @Jack - most people do, specifically noobs like myself.

Comment: @Blahwhore Well, it will be deprecated soon, so I would suggest switching over ;-)

Comment: @Jack - i'll be sure to stick to php5 then, i've used php6 but like you've mentioned, the functions don't work as with php5.

Comment: PDO and mysqli are available in php5 too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `addslashes` function around this variable value in which this `image tag` is coming. It the error of single `slashes`.

Comment: @dowvoter, can you tell me the reason of downvoting the answer?

Comment: Using `addslashes()` is bad practice for escaping SQL; it has its own function, depending on the library used.

Comment: But if `PHP` provides us the function then why not use it?

Comment: I have no idea why PHP provides `addslashes()` (never had to use it) but it should definitely not be used to escape string variables in SQL  knowing there are better functions to accomplish it.

Comment: You are more experienced than us that's y u know more functions than us, but if we just know this function and use it to good effect then i don't think that there is any issue in using it knowing that i don't know too many functions.

Comment: We're all here to learn new things, so I'll leave you with [this article](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) that discusses the merits of one over the other.

Comment: @DeadMan - sorry for the late response, stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to approve the answer until a few minutes after i responded to you and well... been kinda busy. But overall, you are a LIFE SAVER! :D

Answer (score 0):

You're using single quotes in the `src` attribute, but then you wrap the whole thing in single quotes too, so that won't work:

```
$share_text = '<img src="http://dosha.re/i/Uvhg.png" />';
$sql .= ", '$share_text'";
```

Alternatively, and probably better, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `PDO::quote` or `mysqli::real_escape_string`.

```
$sql .= sprintf(", '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($share_text));
```

It's impossible to tell from this what your real query is, but I would suggest using prepared statements so that you don't have to worry about escaping SQL.